# PSD to HTML - How can I execute my background graphics?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to start my first web-site and I've created my layout in Photoshop but I don't know how to go about placing my graphical elements into proper 'divs' for what I'm trying to accomplish with it.

Here is the layout I came up with,

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, firstly with the header, I want the colored lines (threads) to expand 100% of your browser width while the logo stays centered.  I tried doing this but with the entire width of those threads in one .png file (image size about 100px by 1200px) but this seems problematic.

With the 'content area' graphic below my header, which is a sort of box with an inward perspective, I want to keep the integrity of the edges of the box whilst the height fluctuates from time to time depending on how much content is in place.  How can I execute this right?  I tried making a container div with my box as the background image, with a height of 100% but the image does not seem to scale.

Comment: This doesn't really fit the Q&A format of stackoverflow. Try googling "basics of html and css" or "how to convert psd to html"

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so based on how well-made your layout is, I assume that you've already divided everything into layers. If you haven't, then do that.

Next, note that we typically use repeating patterns nowadays. We used to use giant images that scaled down, but that used up a lot of data and since design patterns have changed to be more simplistic, we just use patterns.

All your text can easily be done in CSS, so we'll ignore that.

Next, hide every layer except the one element you're dealing with and go to file>save for web. Make sure you choose a file format that allows for transparency. You're probably going to have quite a few elements if you want to replicate your design exactly: the logo, the beads, a 5 or so pixel-wide strip of your strings, a horizontal border, a vertical border, and another image for each corner of your border. You could also use one image and rotate them in CSS3 but that isn't as widely supported.

Next, learn some HTML and CSS. Seriously, don't bite off more than you can chew.

After you know how to do that, then separate your site into multiple divs: a header, a navigation, and a body.

For the header, set the background to your little strip and set the background-repeat to x.

Put the logo inside the header and set the margin to "0 auto." This will center it.

Again, just use CSS for the text.

Finally, for your body border with perspective... This one is a little harder. You could create 3  divs and use top, sides, body instead of having sides +corners. Or you could stick with that and create 4 divs: one for each edge and one for each corner.

However, I would just stick with CSS for your border. It's a little hard to apply what I said to do and you would have to remove lighting so that it tiles well. With CSS3 you can set some cool shadows if you want to do extrusions.

Note that you don't have to do it this way, this is just how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go through this step by step with you. First, you need to separate out your Photoshop in different layers. When slicing out layers and parts of your Photoshop file, try to keep the images as small as possible. For example, the your colored lines do not have to be a 100px by 1200px image. It can be a 100px by 10px image that repeats.

You can combine the logo and the threads/colored lines together in the header:

```
<header>
  <img src="logo.png" />
</header>
```

The logo would go in the `<img>` tag and the threads (that you have cut down into a repeating 100px by 10px image) would go in the background of the header. The CSS would look something like this:

```
header {
  background: url('colored_line_threads.png') repeat-x center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The `background-repeat` property `repeat-x` makes sure that the colored lines only repeat along the horizontal axis. THe `background-position` property `center` makes sure that the lines are centered vertically in the `<header>` container.

As for the beveled border around the content, you need to cut out some strategic images from your photoshop file. I suggest making an image with all four corners, an image with the top and bottom horizontal borders, and an image with the left and right vertical borders. Then there's the HTML/CSS component of this problem. I'm sure that there are way better ways to do this, but I came out with a way where we would have a `div` per part of the border.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="border">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="corner">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <p>Some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Here, I've created two `<div>` containers with `<div>` containers inside: one for the four corners and one for the four borders. The CSS would look something like this for the borders:

```
.border div {
  position: absolute;
}

.border div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: url('border_horizontal.png');
  width: 100%; height: 50px;
}

.border div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: url('border_vertical.png');
    width: 50px; height: 100%;
}

.border div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px; left: -15px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.border div:nth-child(2) {
  top: -15px; left: 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.border div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0px; right: -15px;
  background-position: 50px 0px;
}

.border div:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -15px; left: 0px;
  background-position: 0px 50px;
}
```

Each `div` in the border container represents a border of the contents container and we're using repeating images to show the borders. Same thing for the corners, one `div` for each corner:

```
.corner div {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('corners.png');
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}

.corner div:nth-child(1) {
  top: -15px; left: -15px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.corner div:nth-child(2) {
  top: -15px; right: -15px;
  background-position: 50px 0px;
}

.corner div:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -15px; left: -15px;
  background-position: 0px 50px;
}

.corner div:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -15px; right: -15px;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
}
```

You can see the rest of the code and play around it at this CodePen: http://codepen.io/phantomesse/pen/safcK.

This is just one way to structure your HTML and CSS. There are many ways to do this (and probably some better ways), so just keep practicing!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the previous answer in that you can create a pattern with the threads. Crop the layout on the threads vertically. About 10px by however long your thread height is. Then use CSS to repeat the pattern like so:

```
body {
     background-image: url(images/pattern.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

There are many videos on YouTube about this you can start at. [PSD to HTML YouTube videos](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=psd+to+html&oq=psd+to+html&gs_l=youtube.3..0i19l10.361.1880.0.2106.11.7.0.4.4.0.176.713.5j2.7.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.VoLbpzU2NmA)